# how to make XCode not strip debug symbols from the final executable binary file inside ipa in xcode 9.0 with debug configuration?

Tags: ios, xcode

how to keep debug symbols information in the executable binary file inside IPA instead of generating isolated dSYM files and stripping it from the bonary file in Xcode 9.0?

when in XCode 8.3, the default behavior of "xcodebuild -exportArchive" will not generate isolated dSYM files and all the debug symbols will be kept in the executable binary file. It is convenient for debugging during development phase. But after I upgrade Xcode to version 9.0, the default behavior changes to generate isolated dSYM files and strip the debug symbols from the final executable binary file so I can not get readable stack trace during runtime.

Does anyone know how to keep the debug information in the executable binary file, like what happened in XCode 8.3, rather than strip it?

this is the archive command(in python):

```
def export_ipa(options):
  build_opts = '' \
  + ' DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING=NO' \
  + ' STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO' \
  + ' SEPARATE_STRIP=NO' \
  + ' COPY_PHASE_STRIP=NO' \
  + ' DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf'

  build_cmd = 'xcodebuild' \
  + ' -project ' + options.proj_path \
  + ' -configuration ' + 'Debug' \
  + ' -sdk ' + IOS_SDK \
  + ' -scheme ' + IOS_SCHEME \
  + ' ARCHS=\"armv7 arm64\"' \
  + ' -archivePath ' + options.archive_path \
  + ' CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=' + options.cert \
  + ' DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=' + IOS_TEAM_ID \
  + ' ' + build_opts \
  + ' clean ' \
  + ' archive'

  os.system(build_cmd)

  pck_cmd = 'xcodebuild' \
  + ' -exportArchive ' \
  + ' -archivePath ' + options.archive_path \
  + ' -exportOptionsPlist ' + options.explist \
  + ' -exportPath ' + options.ipa_path

  os.system(pck_cmd)
```

and this is the exportOptionList:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Is it about a released version (no matter if Test-flight or App Store)?

Comment: no, it is a debug version.

Comment: Why do you archive it?

Comment: to make it convenient to distribute it to QA teams